# Int values changing drastically and segmentation faults

Tags: c++, class, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I've been trying to learn C++ lately, and I'm working on making a linked list of intervals that have no intersection, but i've been getting some really weird errors. My integers (obtained from get_bi or get_bs) give some pretty ridiculous values after I run the reuinion function the second time. Since those values lead to some unintended behaviour, I get segmentation faults. I thought that was the root of the problem, but I'm not sure how to fix them. I don't think I'm accessing pointers that point to nothing or whatever is causing that.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Uinter
    /*
     * Regrouping class for intervals (_Inter class) 
     * offering 3 different methods:
     *  "reunion(int bi, int bs)" -> Unites the interval pointed by "_tete"
     *                               with the one defined by [bi, bs]
     *  "printUinter()"           -> Prints the interval pointed by "_tete"
     *  "contient(int nb)"        -> Returns True if "nb" is present inside
     *                               the intervals, else False. 
     */
    {
        class _Inter
        /*
         * Class representing a single interval.
         * _bi stands for the lower limit of the interval.
         * _bs stands for the upper limit of the interval.
         */
        {
            int _bi, _bs;
            _Inter* _next;
        public:
            _Inter(int _bi, int _bs, _Inter* _next)
                {
                this->_bi = _bi;
                this->_bs = _bs;
                this->_next = _next;
                cout<<"_Inter created with bi, bs and _next = " << _bi << " , "<< _bs << " , " << _next <<endl;  
                };

                // Defining getters and setters for the interval.

            void set_bi(int value)
                {cout <<"setting bi = "<< _bi << endl;
                _bi = value;}

            void set_bs(int value)
                {cout <<"setting bs = "<< _bi << endl;
                _bs = value;}

            void set_next(_Inter* value)
                {_next = value;}

            int get_bi()
                {cout <<"getting bi = "<< _bi << endl;
                return _bi;}

            int get_bs()
                {cout <<"getting bs = "<< _bs << endl;
                return _bs;}

            _Inter* get_next()
                {cout << "next = " << _next << endl;
                return _next;}

            void print_self()
                {
                cout << "[" << this->_bi << ";" << this->_bs << "]" << endl;
                }
        };
        _Inter* _tete;
    public:
        Uinter(): _tete(nullptr){}
        void reunion(int bi, int bs)
            {
            if(_tete == nullptr)
                {cout << "Case 1" << endl;
                _Inter new_interval = _Inter(bi, bs, nullptr);
                _tete = &new_interval;
                cout << "_tete after Case 1 end = " << _tete << endl;
                cout << "_tete values after Case 1 end = " << _tete->get_bi() << " " << _tete->get_bs() << " " << _tete->get_next() << endl;
                cout << "_tete->get_next() == nullptr = " << (_tete->get_next() == nullptr) << endl;
                }
            else
                {cout << "Case 2" << endl;
                if(bi < _tete->get_bi())
                    {cout << "Case 2.1" << endl;
                    if (bs < _tete->get_bi())
                        {cout << "Case 2.1.1" << endl;
                        _Inter new_interval = _Inter(bi, bs, _tete);
                        _tete = &new_interval;
                        }

                    else if (bs > _tete->get_bs())
                        {cout << "Case 2.1.2" << endl;
                        _tete->set_bi(bi);
                        _Inter* temp;
                        temp = _tete->get_next();
                        while (temp != nullptr &&bs > temp->get_bs())
                            {cout << "Case 2.1.2 while" << endl;
                            temp = temp->get_next();
                            }
                        if (temp == nullptr)
                            {cout << "Case 2.1.2.1" << endl;
                            _tete->set_bs(bs);
                            _tete->set_next(nullptr);
                            }
                        else
                            {cout << "Case 2.1.2.2" << endl;
                            _tete->set_bs(temp->get_bs());
                            _tete->set_next(temp->get_next());
                            }
                        }

                    else if (bs > _tete->get_bi())
                        {cout << "Case 2.1.3" << endl;
                        _tete->set_bi(bi);
                        }                   
                    }
                else if (bi > _tete->get_bi())
                    {cout << "Case 2.2" << endl;
                    if (bi > _tete->get_bs())
                        {cout << "Case 2.2.1" << endl;
                        _Inter* temp;
                        temp = _tete->get_next();

                        while(temp != nullptr && bi > temp->get_bs())
                            {cout << "Case 2.2.1 while" << endl;
                            temp = temp->get_next();
                            }
                        if (temp == nullptr)
                            {cout << "Case 2.2.1.1" << endl;
                            _Inter new_interval = _Inter(bi, bs, nullptr);
                            temp->set_next(&new_interval);
                            }
                        else if (bi < temp->get_bi())
                            {cout << "Case 2.2.1.2" << endl;
                            if (bs < temp->get_bi())
                                {cout << "Case 2.2.1.2.1" << endl;
                                _Inter new_interval = _Inter(temp->get_bi(), temp->get_bs(), temp->get_next());
                                temp->set_bi(bi);
                                temp->set_bs(bs);
                                temp->set_next(&new_interval);
                                }

                            else if (bs > temp->get_bs())
                                {cout << "Case 2.2.1.2.2" << endl;
                                temp->set_bi(bi);
                                temp->set_bs(bs);
                                }

                            else if (bs > temp->get_bi())
                                {cout << "Case 2.2.1.2.3" << endl;
                                temp->set_bi(bi);
                                }                   
                            }
                        else if (bi > temp->get_bi())  // bi < temp.get_bs()
                            {cout << "Case 2.2.1.3" << endl;
                            if (bs > temp->get_bs())
                                {cout << "Case 2.2.1.2.1" << endl;
                                temp->set_bs(bs);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    else if (bi < _tete->get_bs())
                        {// bi > tete->get_bi() et bi < _tete->get_bs()
                        cout << "Case 2.2.2" << endl;
                        _Inter* temp;
                        temp = _tete;
                        while (temp != nullptr && bs > temp->get_bs())
                            {cout << "Case 2.2.2 while" << endl;
                            temp = temp->get_next();    
                            }
                        if (temp == nullptr)
                            {cout << "Case 2.2.2.1" << endl;
                            _tete->set_bs(bs);
                            _tete->set_next(nullptr);
                            }
                        else
                            {// bi > tete->get_bi() et bi < _tete->get_bs() et bs < temp->get_bs()
                            cout << "Case 2.2.2.2" << endl;
                            if(bs > temp->get_bi())
                                {cout << "Case 2.2.2.2.1" << endl;
                                _tete->set_bs(temp->get_bs());
                                _tete->set_next(temp->get_next());
                                }
                            else
                                {cout << "Case 2.2.2.2.2" << endl;
                                _tete->set_bs(bs);
                                _tete->set_next(temp);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        void printUinter()
            {
            }

        bool contient(int nb);
    };


int main() 
{
    Uinter interval;
    interval.reunion(12, 23);
    interval.printUinter();
    cout << "___________" << endl;
    interval.reunion(24,36);
    interval.printUinter();
    cout << "___________" << endl;
    interval.reunion(0,11);
    interval.printUinter();
    cout << "___________" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result I get when I run my compiler (I don't really know what it represents, since it just says "Run failed").

```
> Case 1
> _Inter created with bi, bs and _next = 12 , 23 , 0
> _tete after Case 1 end = 0x23ca90 next = 0 getting bs = 23 getting bi = 12
> _tete values after Case 1 end = 12 23 0 next = 0
> _tete->get_next() == nullptr = 1
> ___________ Case 2 getting bi = -17000128 getting bi = -17000128 Case 2.2 getting bs = 3 Case 2.2.1 next = 0x1fefcb6c0
> 
> RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 274ms)
```

I've read that running a debugger might help, but running the debugger in NetBeans 8.0.2 (gdb) only gives me a segmentation error and no real information on it, so I'm not really sure how to fix it. It highlights a line:

```
    int get_bs()
        {cout <<"getting bs = "<< _bs << endl;
        return _bs;}
```

But I'm not really sure how I'm suppose to interpret that, since there are no pointers or whatever on that line.

[image: Here is what I get on my debugger]

Comment: Why does everything have underscores in front of it?

Comment: Yes, I would ask the same question. Some of the elements from this are given for the exercise, and as such I kept them the same. _bi, _bs, _tete and _Inter all had underscores, so I dried keeping them that way. I wouldn't do it like that, but I've read somewhere that it had a conventional meaning. Don't remember what it was though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a class member called `_tete`:

```
        _Inter* _tete;
```

You initialize the class member with the address of a "stack" allocated object (a local object).

```
                _Inter new_interval = _Inter(bi, bs, nullptr);
                _tete = &new_interval;
```

Once the function returns and the object is reused, `_tete` will not be NULL, but will point to an invalid object.

Also, `_tete` is not initialized by `_Inter::_Inter()`.

---

A full description of the C++ memory model is beyond the scope of this answer, but suffice it to say that an object is only valid while it exists. A pointer to an object is only valid so long as the object is valid. A local object is only valid in the local scope where it is defined.

```
Foo *a_ptr = NULL;
if (condition) {
    Foo a; // a is local to the statement block
    a_ptr = &a;
    //...
}          // a has been destructed (it no longer exists)
           // a_ptr points to an invalid object
```

If you want to create an object and have it survive beyond the scope where it was created, you need to use some sort of dynamic memory allocation. In C++, this can be accomplished by using `new`. Typically, if an object is created with `new`, it would need to be destroyed with `delete`. This kind of memory management thus requires manual tracking of when the code is finished with an object so that the appropriate clean up can be applied.

```
Foo *a_ptr = NULL;
if (condition) {
    a_ptr = new Foo(/*...*/);
    //...
}
delete a_ptr; // Note that delete does not set the argument to NULL
```

Scripting languages typically handle this in an automated way, with some kind of garbage collection facility and/or reference counting. C++ does not specify any garbage collection facility, but smart pointers are included with the standard C++ library. The smart pointer automates tracking when the code is finished with an object, and will make sure the appropriate clean up occurs when the object is no longer being referenced. In this case, it seems `_tete` can be made into a `unique_ptr`.

```
    std::unique_ptr<_Inter> _tete;
    //...
        _tete.reset(new _Inter(bi, bs, std::nullptr));
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer! I am sorry, I am still new to c++ and It's quite different from python in this aspect. What I thought I was doing was declaring _tete as a pointer to an _Inter class object, then creating an _Inter class object, and assigning its address to _tete. Is declaring _tete not initializing it? And yes, _tete will not be NULL, but isn't that the normal behaviour of a linked list? I mean _tete is the head element of the list, so when the first element is created, I thought all I had to do was stock it in _tete. Was I wrong in thinking that?

Comment: I guess the problem lies in the fact that the old "new_interval" disappears when I created a new one, but doesn't this work in the same way as a namespace? Assigning a different element to a name just destroys the link between the old element and the name, but shouldn't the element remain in the memory?

Comment: Since you are coming from a scripting background, look into using a smart pointer. I will post an example soon.